# "There is an internal problem with your device, and it might be unstable until you factory data reset."

Tags: system-error, moto-x

On boot, I'm getting the message:

> There is an internal problem with your device, and it might be unstable until you factory data reset.

I'm experiencing no force closes or instability.

What circumstances cause this error, and is there some terminal magic which can avert the need for a factory reset?

If this is a problem with a [`/system/build.prop` mismatch](http://forum.xda-developers.com/nexus-9/development/fix-build-prop-variety-fix-aka-contact-t3133347), how can I find out the specific mismatches so I can restore those?

I'm running Dirty Unicorns on a Moto Pure/Play, but I've seen this on other ROMs and hardware.

Comment: [see this](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=64268577&postcount=10)

Comment: Also clearing /cache might help as [technobill](https://productforums.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/nexus/qgnWWBIHI0A) says *The error message you see on boot is due to system files being out of sync*

Comment: Wiping cache didn't help

Comment: On Nexus phones this is caused by mismatching ROM and `vendor` partition. Moto phones surely doesn't have that partition, but I'm guessing that it will happen when your custom ROM is on a different build number from the underlying official build, in a similar manner. Whatever it is, just ignore it - as long as both are up-to-date, you should encounter no actual errors.

Comment: ........ To continue the statement of @AndyYan There can be the odd.. weirdness. I had a similar problem, and my PIN was reversed

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You guessed correctly. It is a mismatch between the build fingerprint mentioned in the build.prop file in the system partition and the build.prop file in the vendor image, specifically the `ro.vendor.build.fingerprint` key.

As fas as I know, that happens when the vendor partition and system partition were built separately from different builds or versions.

There are several fixes for this issue, I'll specify two I've personally tried and successfully got rid of this annoying error message.

**Runtime Fix**

The first fix is in runtime and requires root access on adb. We'll mount the images and just make the fingerprint value match by copying it from one partition to the other.

- adb root
- mount -o rw,remount -t ext4 /system
- adb remount
- adb pull /vendor/build.prop ./build.prop.vendor
- adb pull /system/build.prop ./build.prop.system
- copy the value from build.prop.system to build.prop.vendor for ro.vendor.build.fingerprint
- adb push ./build.prop.vendor /vendor/build.prop
- adb reboot

**Compile Time Fix**

The second fix I like more because it actually removes the check completely from the code. If you are building your own Android flavor, or at least compiling it yourself you can just change the code and disable this feature.

The code that checks the fingerprint and eventually raises that error is found in

`/frameworks/base/core/java/android/os/Build.java`.

Look for the following method:

`public static boolean isBuildConsistent()`

Simply comment out all the code in it and replace it with

`return true;`

This will make your build always "consistent" and no fingerprint problems will ever be raised.

Comment: https://github.com/LineageOS/android_vendor_lineage/commit/27180809c594cf6beeaeb206cced6fa42c086517

Comment: The third solution that @xdevs23 mentioned, is to actually make the fingerprints match :)

Comment: Exactly, I picked that commit and never got that message again.